# AnguralUI Calendar initialising issue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement angular-ui calendar. I installed all the needed dependencies with **bower**, included scripts in following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
```

HTML is following:

```
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="calendarOptions.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" ng-controller="MyController"></div>
```

JavaScript code is following:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
/* config object */
$scope.eventSources = {
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2014-07-19'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2011-07-20'
        }
    ],
    color: 'red',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
};

$scope.calendarOptions = {
    calendar:{
        height: 300,
        editable: true,
        header:{
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next basicWeek month agendaDay'
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            $('.calendar-input').show();
            console.log(this)
            $('#create-event').click(function() {
                $scope.eventSources.events.push({
                    title: 'Event2',
                    start: '2014-07-20',
                    end: '2014-07-22'
                });

                $('.calendar-input').hide();
            });
        },
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
    }
};
});
```

UI is working fine for me, buttons also work fine when switching between calendar modes (basicWeek, month and agendaDay). 
But, when I refresh the page I can see 4 identical errors in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.getTokens     (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular-ui-    calendar/src/calendar.js:86:36)
at Scope.$digest (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12439:40)
at Scope.$apply (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12712:24)
at file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1419:15
at Object.invoke (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3918:17)
at doBootstrap (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1417:14)
at bootstrap (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1431:12)
at angularInit (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1344:5)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/angular/angular.js:21817:5)
at j (file:///Users/vtaliar/Dropbox/Phil/Company/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:26860) angular.js:9997
(anonymous function) angular.js:9997
(anonymous function) angular.js:7299
Scope.$digest angular.js:12466
Scope.$apply angular.js:12712
(anonymous function) angular.js:1419
invoke angular.js:3918
doBootstrap angular.js:1417
bootstrap angular.js:1431
angularInit angular.js:1344
(anonymous function) angular.js:21817
j jquery.js:3073
k.fireWith jquery.js:3185
n.extend.ready jquery.js:3391
```

As you can see, I'm trying to show two events when page is loaded, but I'm not able to. Also, on dayClick event I want to extend my model and add one more event on calendar.

The documentation says, that when clicking on some cell (dayClick events fires) *this* should point to current clicked td element, but in my case this is pointing to *window* somehow.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? 
I have no much experience working with Angular so, maybe, I've made some mistake here. Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

eventsources should be array of array of event objects. Change your eventsources to something like following..

```
    $scope.events = [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2014-07-19'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2011-07-20'
        }
    ];
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It works fine when calendar loads. But when I'm trying to add event dynamically like this: 
                    $scope.eventSources[0].push({
                        title: 'Event3',
                        start: '2014-07-25'
                    }); 
 it doesn't work

Comment: it should work ideally.. may be a digest cycle issue. try to add in $apply . it will fire digest cycle.. if not just add a fiddle or something.. it will be much better..

Comment: This is close, but the var events, should be $scope.events, then it will register when appended too.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering a few things so I created a Plunk to check this out.

Only problem I found is `dayClick` passes 4 arguments `(event, date, jsEvent, view)` this is likely why you got a window object, adding event passes the element back in my testing.

The length error refers to GetTokens, which looking at the calendar code shows it refers to the length of the configuration array. Make sure your array is closed properly and doesn't have any errant semicolons, you cut off the end of the function so I can't say for sure.

Everything else seems okay, I had to include moment.js but you should be getting an error about missing moment if that's the case for you, Bower probably took care of that.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AIHgM2lz5OlmzOVGroQ0?p=info

Documentation used:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed one issue: there no errors in console anymore. But my events are not displayed and *dayClick* still points to *window*. Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Vov4yk I can't say for sure without knowing more about the code. I would expect that you're running into a scope issue, so firing off `{{eventSources}}` to see if that's proper is one thing to do. You may be getting window from the `.show()` command, I'm not 100% sure but put `console.log(this);`at the top of the `dayClick` to see if that's happening. I'm away for a bit but I'll take another look at this tonight.